Who are Shankara and Kal Bhairava according to Kashmir Shaivism?
According to Shiva Purana, Shiva first manifests in the form of 5 headed Sadashiva in the beginning, after that comes Shankara which is the form in which he resides on Kailasha along with Ma parvati and Kal Bhairava is said to be an ansh avatara of Shankar (Shiva).
Does Trika hold the same belief? Which Svacchanda Bhairava (same as Sadashiva I guess?) appearing first and After that Shankara and Kal Bhairava being an ansh avatara.
Or does Trika even belive in the existence of Shankar?
Whenever in trika texts there is a conversation between Bhairav and Bhairavi, is it Svacchanda Bhairavab or Shankara or Kal Bhairava or some one else?
If it is Svacchanda Bhairava or Shankara or someone else then who is Kal Bhairav according to Kashmir Shaivism?
Also, when Shiva appeared in Rishi Vasuguptas dream was it Svacchanda Bhairava or Shankar?
